# Layout arrangement in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to work on this Instagram layout using React Native:

[image: Instagram User Profile screenshot]

However, I'm unable to arrange the layout properly. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import StatusBarBackground from './StatusBarBackground';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <StatusBarBackground />
          <View style={styles.user_profile}>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./images/user_profile.jpg')}/>
              </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.numbers}>128</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.grey_text}>posts</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.numbers}>256</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.grey_text}>followers</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.numbers}>184</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.grey_text}>following</Text>
                  </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                <Button title="Edit Profile" color="#000" backgroundColor="#CCC" raised={true} onPress={this.onPressEditProfile} />
              </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }

  onPressEditProfile(event) {
    console.log('Clicked Edit Profile');
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  user_profile: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 120,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 100,
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  grey_text: {
    color: '#999',
  },
  numbers: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#CCC',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

It looks like this now:

[image: Current look]

What did I miss in the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just applied `flexDirection: 'row'` to common container so it was cause of your result layout.
I've provided some pseudocode just for your understanding.

[image]

```js
const style = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {},
 infoTopRow: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  alignItems: 'center',
 },
 infoBottomRow: {
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
 },
});

<View style={...}>
  <Avatar/>
  <View style={...}> {/*  <---- here should be flexDirection: 'column' or just don't set any value for it */}
 <View style={style.infoTopRow}>
   <InfoBlock title="posts" value="128" />
   <InfoBlock title="followers" value="256" />
   <InfoBlock title="following" value="184" />
 </View>
    <View>
     <Button title="Edit Profile" />
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Combining both answers fixed the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one more wrapper column view

```
<View>
    <StatusBarBackground />
    <View style={styles.user_profile}>
        //Make this container something like flex:0.2
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./images/user_profile.jpg')}/>
        </View>
        // You need another column view wrapper
        <View style={{flex:0.8}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.numbers}>128</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.grey_text}>posts</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.numbers}>256</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.grey_text}>followers</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.numbers}>184</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.grey_text}>following</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                <Button title="Edit Profile" color="#000" backgroundColor="#CCC" raised={true} onPress={this.onPressEditProfile} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Yes, it works when I set as you instructed, almost. The "Edit Profile" button is out of place.